# Css Position With list of double elements

Tags: html, css

Why is it that when creating a simple list with an image as bulletpoints you need at least three elements per entry? Or is there some way to get the entries in a new line without the container div and still have everything align correctly? Perhaps this requires an indepth analysis of position property and floating.

So something like:

```
[div]
  [img] [inner div]
 [/div]
```

Vs:

```
 [img] [inner div]
```

Comment: You could use a `<ul>` with the CSS `list-style-image` property?

Comment: Right, I found a solution but I am mostly trying to understand why it didnt work with just an image a div, and even though I got it to work I dont fully understand why the simpler entries dont quite work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is actually not true.

1. You can use `pseudo elements` for the image and
2. the content doesn't necessarily need to be wrapped in a separate div.

Check out this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/AsnKX/2/)**

Comment: Sorry I meant to ask without the involvement of li. I am not trying to find a way to fix it, just understand why. Without the use of outer divs (or li) I was not able to get the correct positioning.

Comment: @Littlebitconfused I edited the fiddle using divs instead of list elements

Comment: Interesting, didnt knowI could do that. I suppose I was forcing the elements to be inline but then I would need a br or some other way to force the next element to be on a new line so the outer div was essentially a br by being left as a block element. I think I understand now.